# How to use transform:scale() on an iframe without antialiasing?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to prevent the browser from anti-aliasing an iframe element that has had a scale transformation applied? I want it to remain pixellated rather than having the renderer try to smooth the pixels on resize (I want "nearest neighbor" rather than "bicubic" resampling).

I have tried all of the following CSS rules on the iframe (any many combinations of the same), none seems to work in Chrome of Firefox:

```css
transform: scale(2);
image-rendering: pixelated;
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
image-rendering: crisp-edges;   

transform: perspective(1px) scale(2);
backface-visibility: hidden;

transform: translateZ(1px) scale(2);
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution right before I posted this question: The iframe contents ignore `image-rendering: pixelated;` from the parent page, even though the transform works fine. I achieved pixellation by adding `image-rendering: pixelated;` to the HTML/CSS inside the iframe.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was trying to scale up pixelart and it looked terrible.